# Multiple camera processes running at the same time

Tags: python, camera

Is it possible to get two camera instances running at the same time - one is for capturing live feed to stream across network, the other one records video when motion is detected (PRI sensor is used)? I am using Picamera library and it is capable of recording multiple streams using splitter_port. I've tried using multiprocessing (this is a very basic example) :

```python
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import picamera
cam = picamera.PiCamera()

def loop_a():
    while 1:
        try:
           cam.start_recording('/home/pi/bin' + 'video1.h264')
           time.sleep(20)
           cam.stop_recording()
       except KeyboardInterrupt:
          cam.close()

def loop_b():
    while 1:
        try:
            cam.start_recording('/home/pi/bin' + 'video2.h264', splitter_port=2)
            time.sleep(20)
            cam.stop_recording(splitter_port=2)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
          cam.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=loop_a).start()
    Process(target=loop_b).start()
```

but it doesn't work as I get the following error: `Camera component couldn't be enabled: Out of resources (other than memory)`
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion). Based on your question I think it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: It does, but it has a few massive drawbacks - streaming across network has a maximum of 1 FPS. And the fram rate on recorded videos is not greater due to requiring a massive amount of processing power. So Motion isn't really a solution for a decent security project.

Comment: I'm using it with a Pi2 that is overclocked. No issues w/ 20fps for video, and 2fps for streaming.